# How to customize design in PagedList.MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Can anyone help me out to add or update CSS classes and HTML in PagedList.MVC

This is my **Index.cshtml**

```
<span>Page</span> @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) <Span>of</Span> @Model.PageCount
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
```

When I have inspected in browser I got below Html

```
<div class="pagination-container">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="active"><a>1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/abc/?page=2">2</a></li>
        <li class="PagedList-skipToNext"><a href="/abc/?page=2" rel="next">»</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Instead of above HTML I need this HTML

```
<div>
    <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why? Your `href="#"` means that your page numbers would not redirect. Are you trying to use some javascript to redirect?

Comment: @StephenMuecke this is just the Html I want don't worry about href, like I want to add page-link class which is not there

Comment: The plugin generates the html. Unless you want to write your own plugin, then you only choice is to use javascript to add it. But again why? - you can create you own css to style the `li` elements anyway you want - what is the reason for adding your own class name?

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks, actually I am using bootstrap 4 in my project so these classes are not picking the style therefore I need those classes in li to work with bootstrap 4

Comment: Create you own css file - `ul.pagination li { .... }` etc to add the styles you want

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks I have wrote custom css for this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use X.PagedList (which is a fork of troygoode's PagedList), you can make use of the `PageClasses` option in `PagedListRenderOptions`.

Here's how you would achieve the classes that Bootstrap 4 is looking for:

```
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts, page => 
    Url.Action("Index", new { page = page }), 
    new PagedListRenderOptions {
        LiElementClasses = new string[] { "page-item" },
        PageClasses = new string[] { "page-link" }
})
```

[See documentation here.](https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList#bootstrap-4-pager-example)

Comment: I'm finding trouble on applying this: 'PagedListRenderOptions' does not contain a definition for 'PageClasses'.

Comment: @Machado I'm having the same trouble, supposedly the nuget package comes with a pagerlist.css which one would have to include, but I'm not sure of the location of said file, so I don't know how to add it.

Comment: Just an FYI there is a small bug with the 'elipses' I've commented on it here.
https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList/issues/173
I suggest to just edit your css to compensate

Answer (score 4):

This way works for me:

first import on top of the page:
@using X.PagedList.Mvc.Core.Common;

and than use like this:

```
   @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }), new PagedListRenderOptions
               {                       
                        DisplayLinkToIndividualPages = true,
                        DisplayPageCountAndCurrentLocation = false,
                        MaximumPageNumbersToDisplay = 10,
                        LiElementClasses = new string[] { "page-item" },
                   PageClasses = new string[] { "page-link" },
                   
                    })
```